# Class inheritance with iterable properties in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand something in Python.

When I have a property that I want shared across all subclasses, I place it in the parent class. I was expecting that the actual value of this property would be unique for each object instance. However, if this property is iterable and I modify it in one object, the change is made for all other instantiated objects.

```py
class Animal:
    sounds = []
    def add_sounds(self, sound):
        return self.sounds.append(sound)

class Cat(Animal):
    pass

class Dog(Animal):
    pass    

cat = Cat()
cat.add_sounds('meow')

dog = Dog()
dog.add_sounds('bark')

print('The cat says: ' + str(cat.sounds))
print('The dog says: ' + str(dog.sounds))
```

This gives:

```
The cat says: ['meow', 'bark']
The dog says: ['meow', 'bark']
```

... but I was expecting:

```
The cat says: ['meow']
The dog says: ['bark']
```

This doesn't seem to be the case for other variable types like strings or numbers. What am I missing? This is Python 3.7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sounds` is a class attribute shared by all instances. You want an *instance* attribute instead, which is best initialized in `Animal.__init__`.

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sounds = []

    def add_sounds(self, sound):
        self.sounds.append(sound)
```

In your code, since `sounds` doesn't exist as an attribute on an individual instance of `Animal`, `self.sounds` resolves to `Animal.sounds`.

The difference you are observing with strings and numbers is the those types are immutable; you don't specify how you observe the difference, but here's an example:

```
x = 3
y = x
x += 1
assert y == 3
```

The `+=` operator doesn't modify the existing `int` that both `x` and `y` refer to; it creates a new `int` object and makes `x` refer to that, leaving `y` as the sole reference to the previous `int` object.